# Calculate Chld Accounts from Parent Accounts ..For this Modify Existing Query

Tags: apex, soql

```
[SELECT Total_Account_Revenue__c ,ParentId,Count__c, (SELECT id,COUNT_DISTINCT(id), Sales_to_Date__c FROM  ChildAccounts) FROM Account WHERE   id in :ParentIds GROUP BY ParentID]
```

when `Count(ID)` given in Query we get error

> only root queries support aggregate expressions

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you can't use aggregate expressions in child queries. Instead, you'd need to aggregate the records directly:

```
AggregateResult[] results = [
  SELECT SUM(Sales_To_Date__c) sumSales, ParentId ParentId
  FROM Account
  GROUP BY ParentId];
```

Then, you can use that information to update the parents:

```
Account[] parents = new Account[0];
for(AggregateResult result: results) {
  parents.add(
    new Account(
      Id=(Id)result.get('ParentId'), 
      Total_Account_Revenue__c=(Decimal)result.get('sumSales')
    )
  );
}
update parents;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SOQL you can get child records list, by using that list you can get the count of child records.

```
Account[] parentAccounts = [SELECT Id, Total_Account_Revenue__c ,ParentId, Count__c, (SELECT Id FROM ChildAccounts) FROM Account WHERE id in :ParentIds];
Map<Id,Integer> childCountsMap = new Map<Id, Integer>();
for(Account parAccObj: parentAccounts){
    childCountsMap.put(parAccObj.id, parAccObj.ChildAccounts.size());
}
```

in the `childCountsMap` map you get all counts.